# DoInit method in controller not executed on page redirecte

Tags: javascript, aura, event

I have an aura component in which

1. for `init` event I am subscribing to message event using `window.addEventListener` and
2. for `aura:locationChange` event I am unsubscribing to the event using `window.removeEventListener`.

Now in case a user uses the browser back button to come back to same component the `doInit` method is not called.

Is there a way to trigger a function when the page opens again.

Here is a sample code

**sample.cmp**

```
<aura:component implements="flexipage:availableForRecordHome,force:hasRecordId">
    <aura:handler name="init" value="{!this}" action="{!c.init}" />
    <aura:handler event="aura:locationChange" action="{!c.handleDestroy}" />
</aura:component>
```

**sampleController.js**

```
({
    init: function (cmp, evt, hlp) {
        // Note: this part is not executed when user
        // opens the component by clicking back button of browser
        window.addEventListener('message', hlp.handler);
    },
    handleDestroy: function (cmp, evt, hlp) {
        window.removeEventListener('message', hlp.handler);
    }
});
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

At the end I solved this problem using UX, I am using a boolean variable to keep track if the subscription is active.(When the user is redirected to a different tab I am setting the boolean to false and unsubscribing to event)

And in UI I am showing a button and a message so user can manually subscribe to event when they come back to page using browser back button.

Answer (score 0):

Looks like you need to use `render` event instead:

> The `init` event is fired **only once** per lifecycle of the component. The
> init event *doesn’t get fired if the component is served from cache*. To
> execute JavaScript code every time a component is rendered, use the
> render event instead.

So for what I understand, when the user uses the browser's back button, the component is served from cache.
Take a look at this article: [Invoking Actions on Component Initialization](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.lightning.meta/lightning/js_cb_init_handler.htm)

Hope it helps.

Comment: Thanks for your response, however onrender event is also not fired when we go back to component using back button because technically there is no rendering there